# PrimeFaces 6, JSF y Java - Comprobar mediante boolean flag y selectBooleanCheckbox, valor required inputText y proceso commandButton de forma dinámica

Tags: jsf, primefaces, required

**Editado (10-8-21):** El código como base, es similar a este:

```
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox
        itemLabel="Reserva mediante telefono"
        value="#{confirmarController.checked}"
        disabled="#{confirmarController.deshabilitarCheckbox and (not confirmarController.controlAsistente)}"
        binding="#{checkbox}"
        rendered="#{confirmarController.posibleTelefonoAtencion}">              
    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

    <h:panelGroup id="pnlTelefono"
        rendered="#{confirmarController.posibleTelefonoAtencion}">
        <p:fieldset
                rendered="#{confirmarController.modoAtencionTelefonica}">
            <p:outputLabel for="telefonoReserva"
                value="Introduzca su tlf"/>
            <p:inputText id="telefonoReserva" mask="999999999" type="tel"
                required="#{not confirmarController.controlAsistente or (checkbox.value == 'true' and (param.confirmarTelefono == 'true'))}" 
                value="#{confirmarController.telefonoReserva}"
                validator="#{confirmarController.validarTelefono}"
                placeholder="Ej: 988677755">
            </p:inputText>
        </p:fieldset>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            
        </script>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <f:facet name="footer">

        <p:commandButton value="Atras"
            action="#{confirmarController.doIrAElegirFecha}"
            icon="ui-icon-atras" inline="true" />

        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-aceptar"
            value="Aceptar"
            action="#{confirmarController.doRegistrarReserva}"
            process="telefonoReserva"
            update="growl @form:pnlDialogosSalir" inline="true"                 
            ajax="false">
            <f:param name="confirmarTelefono" value="#{checkbox.value == 'true' ? 'true' : 'false'}" />
        </p:commandButton>

        <p:commandButton value="Salir"
            onclick="PF('dlgCancelarReserva').show();"
            icon="ui-icon-cancelar" type="button" inline="true" />
    </f:facet>
```

En cuanto al método de validar teléfono, lo acciona validate, de la clase RegexValidator

```
public void validarTelefono (FacesContext contexto, UIComponent componente, Object valor) {
   regexValidator.validate(contexto, componente, valor)
}
```

---

Tengo que desarrollar un módulo en xhtml con PrimeFaces 6, JSF y Java que requiera un inputText y esté controlado principalmente por una bandera booleana, seguido de un selectBooleanCheckbox y un commandButton (el primero es alta, el segundo medio y el tercero baja de prioridad).

La historia de usuario del módulo se inicia de la siguiente manera:

1. Si la bandera principal es verdadera, el check queda vacío por defecto y inputText se queda con required=false.
   Si el usuario decide marcarlo, entonces inputText pasa a required=true, y commandButton tiene un param=true para realizar el process correspondiente.

Si no está marcado, simplemente clic en el commandButton, sin validación de inputText.

2. Si la bandera principal es falsa, el check siempre está marcado y deshabilitado, e inputText siempre es required=true.

Me gustaría mostrar el código, pero tiene datos confidenciales por parte del cliente (siento mucho el inconveniente...), por lo que los siguientes enlaces podrían ayudarlos un poco y brindarles las soluciones factibles para lo que estoy buscando solución:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431751/primefaces-pselectbooleancheckbox-default-checked-state#

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683939/hide-show-inputtext-depends-on-selectbooleancheckbox --> En este caso, que siempre se muestre

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48225348/required-value-from-bean-doesnt-change-back-to-false --> El cambio de true a false, con el orden de prioridad

Muchas gracias por su inestimable ayuda :)

Comment: `Me gustaría mostrar el código, pero tiene datos confidenciales por parte del cliente (siento mucho el inconveniente...),` Haz un [mcve] que no incluya esa información confidencial, y agrégalo a la pregunta

Comment: @SJuan76 Hecho, gracias por la aclaración :)